# AJAX variable to html

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

If I have this code in AJAX success..

```
success: function(msg) {
    var msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
        new_name = msg.Name;
        var html_new_name = new_name;
        $('#new_project_name').append(html_new_name);
        $('#myModalAlertSuccess').modal('show');
    }
```

How can I access the variable `html_new_name` in AJAX to HTML..Like this:

```
<a href='<?php echo base_url('generator/view_generate'.$html_new_name) ?>'>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="view" data-dismiss="modal">
    View
  </button>
</a>
```

So that I can use the variable `html_new_name` to another `method in Controller`.

Or if it is not possible?
Is there any other way?

Comment: on success trigger another ajax call to another controller setting html_new_name as data now in that controller u can use it as php variable and send it to your coresponding view

Comment: please post generated `href` and mention where is `$html_new_name`. then you can use `regex` to generate according url.

Comment: @RonitAdhikari it work like that but I can't view the View file in main window in browser. I can only view in the inspect element-->html

Comment: @TechnoKnol can you site an example?

Comment: first post your generated html of a tag, then I will be able to show you example.

Comment: @user987654321 I have submitted answer have you tried

Answer (score 0):

AJAX success..

```
success: function(msg) {
    var msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
        var link = $("#myLinke").attr('href');
        $("#myLinke").attr('href', link + msg.Name)                

    }
```

html :

```
<a id="myLinke" href='<?php echo base_url('generator/view_generate') ?>'>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="view" data-dismiss="modal">
    View
  </button>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function(msg) {
    var msg = $.parseJSON(msg);
        new_name = msg.Name;
        var html_new_name = new_name;
        $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               data:{'htmlname' : html_new_name},                
               url: '/path/to/your/anothercontroller/post_action',
               success:function(data){
                   alert('it worked');
               }
           });
        $('#new_project_name').append(html_new_name);
        $('#myModalAlertSuccess').modal('show');
    }
```

anothercontroller.php

```
public function post_action()
{   
    if($this->input->post('htmlname') == "")
    {
        $htmldata = "";
    }
    else
    {
        $htmldata = $this->input->post('htmlname');
    }
    echo $this->load->view('template/content', $htmldata,  TRUE);
}
```

Now you can access $htmldata in your corresponding view